# mmap() and locking files

Tags: c, locking, posix, mmap

Consider the following snippet (error handling missing on purpose):

```
void* foo(const char *path, off_t size) {
    int fd;
    void *ret;

    fd = open(path, O_RDWR);
    lockf(fd, F_LOCK, 0);
    ret = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    close(fd);
    return ret;
}
```

So, the idea is to open a file, `mmap()` it and return just the data pointer. It would be great if the file could be locked for mmap-time too.

Per `mmap(3p)`:

> The mmap() function shall add an extra reference to the file associated with the
>   file descriptor fildes which is not removed by a subsequent close() on that file
>   descriptor.   This reference shall be removed when there are no more mappings to
>   the file.

But per `lockf(3p)`:

> File locks shall be released on first close by the locking process of  any  file
>   descriptor for the file.

So, using `lockf()` I'd have to keep the fd open and carry its reference for an awfully long time. Is there a better *portable* method to ensure the file is locked till `munmap()` is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [flock(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock), whose documentation says "the lock is released either by an explicit LOCK_UN operation on any of these duplicate descriptors, or when all such descriptors have been closed."

Comment: Yes, `flock()` works as expected but I'm worried about the portability of it. One thing is where it is available, and the other: whether other (non-glibc) implementations will do the same. I don't see any specific information on that on the BSD manpage but it seems it won't hold it.

Comment: What's the list of platforms you want this to work on?  Would you be willing to have different solutions for different platforms (e.g. using conditional compilation)?

Comment: Well, with this particular project I am targeting POSIX — mostly Linux, maybe some BSDs. The main problem with different solutions is that they'd require changing library API.

Comment: Then I suggest you be pragmatic about it: flock(2) will work on Linux, and I bet it will work on BSD too (you'd just have to test it).

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. You have a few options, in order of ease of use:

- Keep the fd open.
- Put a mutex inside the mapped region.
- Use a separate lock file.

I won't go into details for them here, there are other questions describing them better anyway.