# File retains lock after mmap and close

Tags: c, posix

Possible duplicate: [mmap() and locking files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202750/mmap-and-locking-files)

I just found [a bug](https://github.com/ashegoulding/proone/blob/f5d9956c3e2343455a3025b9d38c539b680da8f5/src/proone.c#L1101) in the project I'm working on as I was reviewing the code for documentation(notice that the fd is not moved to the global storage). The code works as intended on Linux. So I dug further and still have no idea why it works. AFAIK, this could be an interpretation issue.

From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/mmap.html

> The mmap() function shall add an extra reference to the file associated with the file descriptor fildes which is not removed by a subsequent close() on that file descriptor. This reference shall be removed when there are no more mappings to the file.

From FLOCK(2)

> Locks  created  by  flock()  are associated with an open file description (see
> open(2)).  This means that duplicate file descriptors (created by, for example,
> fork(2) or  dup(2))  refer  to the  same lock, and this lock may be modified or
> released using any of these file descriptors. Furthermore, the lock is released
> either by an explicit LOCK_UN operation on any of these  du‐ plicate file
> descriptors, or when all such file descriptors have been closed.

And the snippet I wrote to test this behaviour

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main (const int argc, const char **argv) {
    static const size_t M_SIZE = 1;
    int ec = 0;
    int fd = -1;
    int f_ret;
    const char *path;
    void *m = NULL;

    if (argc <= 1) {
        ec = 2;
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <lock file path>\n", argv[0]);
        goto END;
    }

    path = argv[1];
    fd = open(path, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 0755);
    if (fd < 0) {
        ec = 1;
        perror(path);
        goto END;
    }

    f_ret = flock(fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB);
    if (f_ret != 0) {
        ec = 1;
        perror(path);
        goto END;
    }

    f_ret = ftruncate(fd, M_SIZE);
    if (f_ret != 0) {
        ec = 1;
        perror(path);
        goto END;
    }

    m = mmap(NULL, M_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if (m == MAP_FAILED) {
        m = NULL;
        ec = 1;
        perror(path);
        goto END;
    }

    // This block
    if (true) {
        close(fd);
        fd = -1;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Lock holding ...\n");
    pause();

END:
    if (fd >= 0) {
        close(fd);
    }
    if (m != NULL) {
        munmap(m, M_SIZE);
    }
    return ec;
}
```

My interpretation is that running the program like this:

```sh
./prog /tmp/lock & sleep 1; ./prog
```

must result in both process successfully holding the lock because the program loses the fd. But the second process won't take off because of the lock held by the first process. To confirm this, `lsof` shows that the process holding **mem-W** to the file.

So, the "extra reference" is what making the kernel do some sort of "lazy close"? It makes sense this way though, because you wouldn't want other processes to interfere with the mapped memory acquired. But the exact wordings are "all such file descriptors have been closed"? I wonder how the program would behaviour on other platforms and who's right on this.

Comment: I think your question includes the answer. Your lazy-close theory is correct and your first quotation says it: "which is **not** removed by a subsequent close()". The file remains locked, it's bound to the file, not the file descriptor. And the sentence "all such file descriptors have been closed" doesn't really concern you since you're nowhere duplicating the file descriptor.

Comment: *2 years later* This turned out to be a bug in Linux kernel. https://github.com/dxdxdt/gists/tree/master/flock_mmap